# Mautic & Amazon SES Integration issues

Tags: amazon-ses, mautic, mass-emails

I installed Mautic in-house instance. I tried to integrate it with Amazon SES service. After all was set as needed (please find the attached screenshot below), I clicked "Test connection" button and got the following error:

> Connection could not be established with host
>   email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com [An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. #10013] Log data:
>   ++ Starting Mautic\EmailBundle\Swiftmailer\Transport\AmazonTransport !! Connection could not be established with host
>   email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com [An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. #10013] (code: 0)
>   ++ Starting Mautic\EmailBundle\Swiftmailer\Transport\AmazonTransport

Can someone give a hand on this? What am I doing wrong?

[Screenshot Mautic_Amazon-SES_Integration Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBgg0.png)

Comment: This was fixed by change of the port number to 587

=> edit the AmazonTransport.php line 71 to parent::__construct($host, 587, 'tls');

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by leaving the field "Port" empty (Mautic --> email settings --> Port). Apparently my server wasn't able to use port 25, and leaving this field empty made Mautic find the best port.